# Handler for filter clearing in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I'm using dc.js `filterHandler` function to check when a chart has a filter applied to it. I'm looking for a similar listener that is called when the filter is removed. I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for in the API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.on("postRedraw", function(chart, filter){function()})
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest dc.js on master has functions that allow overriding all of the filter behaviors; these can also be used to watch the filter changes on a more granular level.

It looks like the documentation is missing some headlines at the moment, but search in the docs here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md

for `addFilterHandler`, `removeFilterHandler`, `resetFilterHandler`.

Since these are handlers and not just listeners, you'll need to wrap the current functionality, like so:

```
var rfh = chart.resetFilterHandler();
chart.resetFilterHandler(function(filters) {
     console.log('reset!'); // do what you need here
     rfh(filters)
});
```